# How to use ionic storage (local database) with ngrx in an ionic angular application

Tags: angular, ionic4, ngrx, ionic-storage

How to use ionic storage (local database) with ngrx in an ionic angular application?

I found some resources about using ngrx with a database as an api, or about ionic-storage. But I am stuck in putting them all together (loading data - crud operations - effects - representing observable data ...).

I am trying [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-ngrx-effects-for-data-loading-in-an-ionic-angular-application/)   , but my problem is that it is using http which returns an observable in the dataservice, while I am working with ionic storage which returns a promise.

Notice that it is my first ionic angular application!

I need to know best practices to accomplish this task, where to user promise in this specific case, and if I need to use observable in the state or ...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I have edited the question. Hope it is better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the way I was dealing with the promise (in my code), so I used the same [code in this tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-ngrx-effects-for-data-loading-in-an-ionic-angular-application/).

The difference is that I used ionicstorage instead of getting data with http requests, Ionic storage get() and set() methods return promises but I converted the promises in the dataservice to observables.

At the end my problem was solved - I don't know if I am making best practices!!

Please if you need the entire code tell me and I will be happy to help.